# Pull variable value from javascript source using BeautifulSoup4 Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm newbie in python programming. I'm learning beautifulsoup to scrap website.

I want to extract and store the value of "stream" to my variable.

My Python code as follows :

```
import bs4 as bs #Importing BeautifulSoup4 Python Library.
import urllib.request
import requests
import json
import re

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "http://thoptv.com/partners/mhdTVlive/Core.php?level=1200&channel=Dsports_HD"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")
pattern = re.compile('var stream = (.*?);')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')

for script in scripts:
   if(pattern.match(str(script.string))):
       data = pattern.match(script.string)
       links = json.loads(data.groups()[0])
       print(links)
```

This is the source javascript code to get the stream url value.

> https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/oncyToRO.js'>if( navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)||
>   navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)||
>   navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)||
>   navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)||
>   navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)||
>   navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)||
>   navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {var stream =
>   "http://ssrigcdnems01.cdnsrv.jio.com/jiotv.live.cdn.jio.com/Dsports_HD/Dsports_HD_800.m3u8?jct=ibxIPxc6rkq1yIUJb4RlEV&pxe=1504146411&st=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczRaEwgGl4Dyvly_3HihdlD_Oduojk5Kxs.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABQtNjUxNDEwODczODgxNzkyMzg5OQACUzEAAjYw*";}else{var
>   stream =
>   "http://hd.simiptv.com:8080//index.m3u8?key=VIoVSsGRLRouHWGNo1epzX&exp=932213423&domain=thoptv.stream&id=461";}jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").setup({"title":
>   'thoptv.stream',"stretching":"exactfit","width": "100%","file":
>   none,"height": "100%","skin": "seven","autostart": "true","logo":
>   {"file":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/A55gM.png","margin":"-0",
>   "position":"top-left","hide":"false","link":"http://mhdtvlive.co.in"},"androidhls":
>   true,});jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").onError(function(){jwplayer().load({file:"http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/7RtXk3vl-52qL9xLP.mp4",image:"http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/7RtXk3vl-480.jpg"});jwplayer().play();});jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").onComplete(function(){window.location
>   = window.location.href;});jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").onPlay(function(){clearTimeout(theTimeout);});

**I need to extract the url from stream.**

var stream = "http://ssrigcdnems01.cdnsrv.jio.com/jiotv.live.cdn.jio.com/Dsports_HD/Dsports_HD_800.m3u8?jct=ibxIPxc6rkq1yIUJb4RlEV&pxe=1504146411&st=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczRaEwgGl4Dyvly_3HihdlD_Oduojk5Kxs.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABQtNjUxNDEwODczODgxNzkyMzg5OQACUzEAAjYw*";}

Comment: Did you try using reg ex?

Comment: Where are you getting the part that stats with `https://content..`

Comment: inside <script>

Answer (score 0):

Rather then thinking complicated with regex, if the link is the only  dynamically changing part, you can `split` the string with some known separating tokens.

```
x = """
https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/oncyToRO.js'>if( navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)|| navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {var stream = "http://ssrigcdnems01.cdnsrv.jio.com/jiotv.live.cdn.jio.com/Dsports_HD/Dsports_HD_800.m3u8?jct=ibxIPxc6rkq1yIUJb4RlEV&pxe=1504146411&st=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczRaEwgGl4Dyvly_3HihdlD_Oduojk5Kxs.AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABQtNjUxNDEwODczODgxNzkyMzg5OQACUzEAAjYw";}else{var stream = "http://hd.simiptv.com:8080//index.m3u8?key=VIoVSsGRLRouHWGNo1epzX&exp=932213423&domain=thoptv.stream&id=461";}jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").setup({"title": 'thoptv.stream',"stretching":"exactfit","width": "100%","file": none,"height": "100%","skin": "seven","autostart": "true","logo": {"file":"https://i.imgur.com/EprI2uu.png","margin":"-0", "position":"top-left","hide":"false","link":"http://mhdtvlive.co.in"},"androidhls": true,});jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").onError(function(){jwplayer().load({file:"http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/7RtXk3vl-52qL9xLP.mp4",image:"http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/7RtXk3vl-480.jpg"});jwplayer().play();});jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").onComplete(function(){window.location = window.location.href;});jwplayer("THOPTVPlayer").onPlay(function(){clearTimeout(theTimeout);});
"""
left1, right1 = x.split("Phone/i)) {var stream =")
left2, right2 = right1.split(";}else")

print(left2)
# "http://ssrigcdnems01.cdnsrv.jio.com/jiotv.live.cdn.jio.com/Dsports_HD/Dsports_HD_800.m3u8?jct=ibxIPxc6rkq1yIUJb4RlEV&pxe=1504146411&st=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczRaEwgGl4Dyvly_3HihdlD_Oduojk5Kxs.AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABQtNjUxNDEwODczODgxNzkyMzg5OQACUzEAAjYw"
```

Comment: can u just make the changes in my python code sir ?

Answer (score 0):

`pattern.match()` matches the pattern from the *beginning* of the string. Try using `pattern.search()` instead - it will match anywhere within the string.

Change your for loop to this:

```
for script in scripts:
    data = pattern.search(script.text)
    if data is not None:
        stream_url = data.groups()[0]
        print(stream_url)
```

You can also get rid of the surrounding quotes by changing the regex pattern to:

```
pattern = re.compile('var stream = "(.*?)";')
```

so that the double quotes are not included in the group.

---

You might also have noticed that there are *two* possible `stream` variables depending on the accessing user agent. For tablet like devices the first would be appropriate, while all other user agents should use the second `stream`. You can use `pattern.findall()` to get all of them:

```
>>> pattern.findall(script.text)
['"http://ssrigcdnems01.cdnsrv.jio.com/jiotv.live.cdn.jio.com/Dsports_HD/Dsports_HD_800.m3u8?jct=LEurobVVelOhbzOZ6EkTwr&pxe=1571716053&st=AQIC5wM2LY4SfczRaEwgGl4Dyvly_3HihdlD_Oduojk5Kxs.*AAJTSQACMDIAAlNLABQtNjUxNDEwODczODgxNzkyMzg5OQACUzEAAjYw*"', '"http://hd.simiptv.com:8080//index.m3u8?key=vaERnLJswnWXM8THmfvDq5&exp=944825312&domain=thoptv.stream&id=461"']
```

Comment: the link is dynamic. it will change for every url I ping.

Comment: @SACH: but you are searching for a particular pattern that begins with `var stream =`. Are you saying that the pattern should be different for different URLs? Also, why are you trying to parse the URL as JSON?

Comment: the url is different for every page I fetch.

Comment: @SACH: I don't see why that is a problem. It's up to the server what it generates for the URL, but you are matching on the same `stream` variable and extracting its value. I find that my answer produces similar changing URLs as other answers that you say work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @SACH: answer updated with code that you can easily incorporate into your current code.

Answer (score -1):

> this code works for me

```
import bs4 as bs #Importing BeautifulSoup4 Python Library.
import urllib.request
import requests
import json


headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "http://thoptv.com/partners/mhdTVlive/Core.php?
level=1200&channel=Dsports_HD"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")

scripts = soup.find_all('script')



out = list()
for c, i in enumerate(scripts): #go over list
    text = i.text
    if(text[:2] == "if"): #if the (if) comes first 
        for count, t in enumerate(text): # then we have reached the correct item in the list
            if text[count] == "{" and text[count + 1] == "v" and text[count + 5] == "s": # and if this is here that stream is set
                tmp = text[count:] # add this to the tmp varible
                break # and end
co = 0
for m in tmp: #loop over the results from prev. result
    if m == "\"" and co == 0: #if string is starting
        co = 1 #set count to "true" 1
    elif m == "\"" and co == 1: # if it is ending stop
        print(''.join(out)) #results
        break
    elif co == 1:
        # as long as we are looping over the rigth string
        out.append(m) #add to out list
        pass

result = ''.join(out) #set result
```

> it basicly filters the string manuely.

but if we use user1767754 method (brilliant by the way) we will end up something like this:

```
import bs4 as bs #Importing BeautifulSoup4 Python Library.
import urllib.request
import requests
import json

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = "http://thoptv.com/partners/mhdTVlive/Core.php?level=1200&channel=Dsports_HD"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.text,"html.parser")

scripts = soup.find_all('script')

x = scripts[3].text

left1, right1 = x.split("Phone/i)) {var stream =")
left2, right2 = right1.split(";}else")

print(left2)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me...  Can you just explain the code.